# Photoshop cc 2014 Resonator

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use photoshop cc 2014 with Resonator plugin everything when I export I get this window saying something about moving command not found.Well I try to with photoshop cc 2014 and up I get the same prob.

Sorry if I am new to this.I hope someone can help me for some reason I get this error I don't know why?

Resonator faced with the trouble

3: Error:General Photoshop error occurred.This functionality may not be available in this version of Photoshop.
- The command "Move" is  not currently available this the error I get?

Comment: You may want to contact the extension devs. There could be either error in how you're using it... Or it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plugin is not free, i suggest you to look up at the faq if there's one, or a Read Me file, if not i suggest you to contact the author of the plugin to ask them why it's not working.

Have you try to restart your computer ? (to kill the temp file of photoshop)

Was it working before ? (might not work with this version of the soft)

Have a good day :)

Comment: I fix it it was not in the Group of Layers.